# Using the google API inside of laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-calendar-api

I previously taught my self php, but now I want to migrate to a framework I have chosen Lavarel currently.

I have been able to do this directly in plain php, but I am having problem re-implementing it in the newest version of Lavarel.

I created a controller based on the google Calendar API.

The first step is authenticating, and that is where my problem exists.

I do the setup, display the google permissions, and accept the permissions.  At this point Google does a callback.

If I route the callback to GoogleCalendar@callback then it calls the constructor again re-displaying the google authentication request in an infinite loop.

If I route the callback to another class it gets the tokens, but then the wrong class has the token.  I have placed the token in a database, but how do I transfer execution back to the GoogleCalendar class.

```
return redirect()->action('GoogleCalendar@part2',['code' => $input['code']]);
```

This fails, even though the class and function exist I get an error message like they don't.

I was able to store the token in the user table, however, I need to pass control back to the GoogleCalendar controller with an operative $client string.

Comment: Have you tried following this [tutorial](https://dev.to/tommym9/integrating-google-calendar-with-a-laravel-site-2bd)?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot   Yes, and I find it lacking.  Many things it glosses over.  It doesn't even include enough use commands.  The whole venue thing doesn't work, probably because the correct **use** command is missing.  **use Google_Client** and **use Google_Service_Calendar** are missing.  The author even says some of his work was done for an employer so they couldn't include it.  Once the token is handled I can take it from there.